# How to run jupyter notebook slideshows in a cloud?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, slideshow

I have an instance on google compute engine which I set up in such a way that I can work on jupyter notebooks using my local computers browser. I connect to the VM by typing external ip with port 8888 and I am ready to go.

Now I want to transform one jupyter notebook into slideshows which I want to access somehow. I tried to follow [nbconvert documentation](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#serving-slides-with-an-https-server-post-serve) and I used the following command in my VMs console:

```
jupyter nbconvert your_talk.ipynb --to slides --post serve
```

My VMs console says that:

```
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook your_talk.ipynb to slides
[NbConvertApp] Writing 254651 bytes to your_talk.slides.html
[NbConvertApp] Redirecting reveal.js requests to https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reveal.js/3.5.0
Serving your slides at http://127.0.0.1:8000/your_talk.slides.html
Use Control-C to stop this server
[NbConvertApp] WARNING | No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
```

I understand that it tries to run the slides on VMs web browser. However, the point is that to access this slides from outside the VM. Thus the question:

**Question.** How to host jupyter notebook slides on my VM so that I could access them remotely using my local computer?

Ps. I have file `your_talk.slides.html` which I can access, but it is just static html file.

---

*Note for readers:* If you read this question and you think that I should have used different tags, feel free to change them.

---

**Logs to Marcins suggestion**

```
RequestException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-08768ed6fc86> in <module>()
      1 import datalab.storage as gcs
      2 slides = get_ipython().getoutput('jupyter nbconvert your_talk.ipynb --to slides --stdout')
----> 3 gcs.Bucket('myownbucket').item('slides.html').write_to("".join(slides[1:]),'text/html')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datalab/storage/_item.py in write_to(self, content, content_type)
    222       self._api.object_upload(self._bucket, self._key, content, content_type)
    223     except Exception as e:
--> 224       raise e
    225 
    226 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datalab/storage/_item.py in write_to(self, content, content_type)
    220     """
    221     try:
--> 222       self._api.object_upload(self._bucket, self._key, content, content_type)
    223     except Exception as e:
    224       raise e

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datalab/storage/_api.py in object_upload(self, bucket, key, content, content_type)
    161     url = Api._UPLOAD_ENDPOINT + (Api._OBJECT_PATH % (bucket, ''))
    162     return datalab.utils.Http.request(url, args=args, data=content, headers=headers,
--> 163                                       credentials=self._credentials, raw_response=True)
    164 
    165   def objects_copy(self, source_bucket, source_key, target_bucket, target_key):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datalab/utils/_http.py in request(url, args, data, headers, method, credentials, raw_response, stats)
    153           return json.loads(str(content, encoding='UTF-8'))
    154       else:
--> 155         raise RequestException(response.status, content)
    156     except ValueError:
    157       raise Exception('Failed to process HTTP response.')

RequestException: HTTP request failed: Insufficient Permission
```

Error logs after calling `$ datalab create --verbosity=debug datalab-instance-name`:

```
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.compute.zones.list] with arguments: [--format: "value(name)", --quiet: "True", --verbosity: 
"debug"]
INFO: Display format: "        table(name,
              region.basename(),
              status():label=STATUS,
              maintenanceWindows.next_maintenance():label=NEXT_MAINTENANCE,
              deprecated.deleted:label=TURNDOWN_DATE
        ) value(name)"
DEBUG: (gcloud.compute.zones.list) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Insufficient Permission
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 839, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 772, in Run
    display_info=self.ai.display_info).Display()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/display.py", line 477, in Display
    self._printer.Print(self._resources)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/resource/resource_printer_base.py", line 256, in Print
    for resource in resources:
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/peek_iterable.py", line 206, in next
    return self.__next__()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/peek_iterable.py", line 211, in __next__
    item = self._NextItem()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/peek_iterable.py", line 183, in _NextItem
    return next(self._iterable)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/compute/lister.py", line 924, in __call__
    utils.RaiseException(errors, ListException)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/compute/utils.py", line 123, in RaiseException
    errors))
ListException: Some requests did not succeed:
 - Insufficient Permission
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.zones.list) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Insufficient Permission
A nested call to gcloud failed.
Command: ["gcloud","compute","--verbosity=debug","zones","--quiet","list","--format=value(name)"]
Return code: 1
```

Comment: you want to access to jupyter notebooks or just your one slide show ?

Comment: @mjsameri I can access jupyter notebooks. I have problem with slideshows

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of Google Cloud DataLab? This is basically Jupyter hosting service on GCP. Anyway, the following code snipplet (when run from inside a notebook, Python=3) will take your notebook, convert it to slides and upload to Cloud Storage. You can serve your flies from cloud storage publicly:

```
import datalab.storage as gcs
slides = !jupyter nbconvert <your_notebook>.ipynb --to slides --stdout
gcs.Bucket('<your_bucket_name>').item('slides.html').write_to("".join(slides[1:]),'text/html')
```

To make it public, in your bucket permissions, add "allUsers" member with "Storage Object Viewer" role. Please note this will make your bucket publicly available on the internet.

If you are not using DataLab, you may need to add `datalab.storage` as a dependency to your Python env.

I think it is way easier in your case and safer than configuring firewalls on a VM and exposing it to inbound traffic.

Comment: Your way looks very appealing so I tried it. I followed [DataLab Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstart). I have done 3 first points and the [4th one](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/#deb) I have done on my VM. However, when I call 'gcloud init' on my VM it asks me select some accounts and I end up without permissions. I also tried to just create a new file 'upload_to_bucket.ipynb` and I paste there your code with personalised names. I and up with logs that there is a problem with permissions. (I attach it to my post)

Comment: Ps. I would like to upload slideshows to the bucket straight from my MV, thus I made the 4th step on VM,

Comment: Yes, you need to have your permission sorted out. I won't be able to help with that. This may be as easy as enabling APIs.

Comment: I enabled APIs as in DataLab Quickstart. However, I wonder if I should do the 4th step on my VM. I.e Install and initialize the Cloud SDK on VM as in tutorial. Do I have to call `gcloud init` on VM before I run the code of yours?

Comment: You have VMs configured for a project automatically on GCP, no need to run `gcloud init`. You need this to manage your cloud from outside GCP unless you have a very custom VM, which I do not believe is the case.

Comment: It sounds right, because when I call `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk` on my VM, it says that everything is up to date. Similarly with `gcloud components install datalab`. Ok, so I skipped the 4th point from DataLab Quickstart (before part) and tried to creat Datalab-instance. However, when I call `datalab create datalab-instance-name` I get an error. I would be very gratefull if you would halp me with managining logs, bacause I understand almost nothing. Just that there is problem with permissions.